# INSERT and UPDATE Parameter queries not working when executed from code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having trouble getting three parameter queries to return any results when executed within code.

The queries work fine if I manually execute them, and when I copied the relevant tables, queries and VBA code into a new database to try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it worked fine as well....

My three tables are:

**Table:**  `List_LunchPattern_Names`

- `PatternID` (AutoNumber & Primary Key)
- `Pattern_Name` (Text)

**Table:**  `List_LunchPatterns`

- `PatternID` (Number & Primary Key - Long Integer)
- `Pattern_Step` (Number & Primary Key - Long Integer)
- `LunchStart1`, `LunchEnd1`, `LunchStart2` and `LunchEnd2` (Date/Time - Short Time)

**Table:**  `tmp_LunchPatterns`

- `Pattern_Step` (Number & Primary Key - Long Integer)
  Pre-populated with numbers 1 - 7 representing days of the week.
- `LunchStart1`, `LunchEnd1`, `LunchStart2` and `LunchEnd2` (Date/Time - Short Time)

The three queries are:

**Query:**  `DML_Add_NewLunchPattern_Name`

```
PARAMETERS  New_Pattern_Name Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO List_LunchPattern_Names ( Pattern_Name )
VALUES      (New_Pattern_Name);
```

**Query:**  `DML_Add_NewLunchPattern`

```
PARAMETERS  Pattern_Identifier Long;
INSERT INTO List_LunchPatterns ( 
                PatternID, Pattern_Step, LunchStart1, 
                LunchEnd1, LunchStart2, LunchEnd2 
                                )
SELECT      Pattern_Identifier, Pattern_Step, LunchStart1
            , LunchEnd1, LunchStart2, LunchEnd2
FROM        tmp_LunchPatterns;
```

**Query:** `DML_Clear_tmp_LunchPatterns`

```
UPDATE  tmp_LunchPatterns 
SET     LunchStart1 = NULL, LunchEnd1 = NULL
        , LunchStart2 = NULL, LunchEnd2 = NULL;
```

The code sits behind a button on the `List_LunchPatterns` form:

```
Private Sub btnCreateLunchPattern_Click()

    Dim sResult As String
    Dim sExisting As Variant
    Dim lNewID As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    sResult = InputBox("Please provide a unique name for the new lunch pattern.", "Lunch Patterns")
    sResult = Trim(sResult)
    If Len(sResult) = 0 Then
        'No entry.
    Else
        sExisting = DLookup("Pattern_Name", "List_LunchPattern_Names", "Pattern_Name='" & sResult & "'")
        If sExisting <> "" Then
            'Existing entry.
            MsgBox "'" & sResult & "' already exists.  Please choose another name.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        Else
            'Valid answer.
            Set db = CurrentDb

            'Add the new name to the pattern name list.
            'Add the temporary times into the final table.
            'Clear the temporary table, requery the combo-box for the new name
            With db
                With .QueryDefs("DML_Add_NewLunchPattern_Name")
                    .Parameters("New_Pattern_Name") = sResult
                    .Execute
                End With
                lNewID = DLookup("PatternID", "List_LunchPattern_Names", "Pattern_Name='" & sResult & "'")
                With .QueryDefs("DML_Add_NewLunchPattern")
                    .Parameters("Pattern_Identifier") = lNewID
                    .Execute
                End With
                .QueryDefs("DML_Clear_tmp_LunchPatterns").Execute
            End With

            With Me
                .cmbPattern_Selector.Requery
                .cmbPattern_Selector = lNewID
                .RecordSource = "List_LunchPatterns"
                FilterForm Me, "PatternID=" & .cmbPattern_Selector
            End With

        End If
    End If

EXIT_PROC:

        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "Form_List_LunchPatterns.btnCreateLunchPattern_Click()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

The `FilterForm` procedure used at the bottom of the code is:

```
Public Sub FilterForm(frm As Object, FilterString As String)

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    With frm
        .Filter = FilterString
        .FilterOn = True
    End With

EXIT_PROC:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
    Select Case Err.Number

    Case Else
        DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "mdl_FormFilter.FilterForm()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC
    End Select

End Sub
```

## The question:

If I copy the QueryDefs part of the code and all tables/queries to a new database and run it it works fine, if I manually run each query it works fine, if I run it using this block of code above then `DML_Add_NewLunchPattern_Name` works fine, but the second query only partially works and the last doesn't at all.
The second query adds seven records using the correct `PatternID`, but the start and end times are blank even though the seven records must have come from the temp table which contains the start/end times as expected.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

### Edit:

In trying to keep my question minimal it looks like I missed out a pretty important part.
The `List_LunchPattern_Names` table is used to populate a combo-box on the form which filters the records displayed from `List_LunchPatterns` to the relevant pattern.
The `Row Source` for the combo-box is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 0 AS PatternID
                , '<New Pattern>' AS Pattern_Name 
FROM            SingleRecord 

UNION SELECT    PatternID, Pattern_Name 
FROM            List_LunchPattern_Names 
ORDER BY        PatternID
```

The first option on the combo-box is to create a new pattern.  Choosing this changes the forms `RecordSource` to the temp table so the new pattern can be entered and checked against existing patterns before being finalised.
The code for this is below, and I *think* the problem is that the form needs a refresh or a requery to finish off the change of record source.

```
Private Sub cmbPattern_Selector_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    With Me

        'If the selected pattern is different from the currently
        'active pattern unhide the Assign Pattern button.
        If Not IsNull(OpenArgs) Then
            If .cmbPattern_Selector <> Split(OpenArgs, "|")(2) Then
                .btnAssignLunchPattern.Visible = True
            End If
        End If

        If .cmbPattern_Selector <> 0 Then
            .cmbPattern_Selector.SetFocus
            .btnCreateLunchPattern.Visible = False
            .RecordSource = "List_LunchPatterns"
            FilterForm Me, "PatternID=" & .cmbPattern_Selector
        Else
            .btnCreateLunchPattern.Visible = True
            .RecordSource = "tmp_LunchPatterns"
            .btnAssignLunchPattern.Visible = False
        End If

    End With

EXIT_PROC:

        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "Form_List_LunchPatterns.cmbPattern_Selector_AfterUpdate()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

### Edit 2:

This is turning into more of an exercise in making sure I tested everything correctly first.

It's only the last record I add to the temp table that gets ignored during the update queries - I didn't see this on earlier tests as I was only adding a single record.  For example, adding times to Monday and Tuesday will create a pattern using Monday only, while Tuesday remains in the temp table - even after I execute the query to clear the table.
This leads me to believe that when I exit the control for the time period to click the button which finalises the pattern that record isn't added to the table until after the click event has finished, so at the start of the click event I should either `DoEvents` or save the record.....

Comment: IMHO, if creating a new database with replicated code worked, the problem would likely reside in the old database, but not within the code. One of several possibilities could be a corruption in the database. Or some sort of global variable screwing with your declarations. But, no, it does not appear (to me) that anything is obviously incorrect.

Comment: That's a lot of `With`s, some of them nested. I've noticed oddities with nested `With`s previously that I couldn't diagnose. Can you try to declare all variables explicitly and not use any?

Comment: @Erikvonasmuth I'll try that when I'm back in the office. I just hope it isn't corruption -I've only just finished rebuilding it from text files after losing all the VBA previously.

Comment: Why are you running 'DML_Clear_tmp_LunchPatterns' every time you make a pass through? Doesn't that clear all your temp time periods? I don't see any code that fills those in before you prompt for a new pattern. Unless I'm missing something obvious - that would result in blank times

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have explained that. The form uses `List_LunchPatterns` as its data source. A combo box using `List_LunchPattern_Names` filters the form to the relevant data. The combo box also has a _New Pattern_ option which changes the source to the `tmp_LunchPatterns` table allowing the user to create a new 7 day pattern and compare it against existing patterns before committing it to the final table. Bit off a faff come to think about it now... might be better to use a batch update & not a temp table.

Comment: Sorry I can't imagine that but in any case that's where I'd be checking. Put a Pause Code on the line `With .QueryDefs("DML_Add_NewLunchPattern")` and manually check the tmp table befoe the query is allowed to run. If it's empty you have the problem source. If it's full and it gets filled correctly after you step thru the query then it might need a `DoEvents` before running to insure the data has been processed before your query runs.

Comment: @dbmitch.  Sorry, would've tested earlier but can never take illness into account. :)  After checking the tables it's looking more like a problem with the changing record source as the new times I add after I've changed the source to `tmp_LunchPatterns` do no appear in the table.  I'll add this pretty important detail to the question and probably come up with the solution while doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer was simple, kind of obvious and not likely to get answered on my first iteration of the question as I'd left out the key points (see edits in the question).

The scenario is a `Continuous Form` linked to a table containing seven empty records, save for the Primary Key listing the number range 1 to 7.
The user enters data to one or more of these records and then clicks the *Save* button which transfers all records entered to the final table.

The problem here is that the controls you entered data into and the button are on the same form so the last record entered isn't saved when you click the button.
While looking up the order of events to explain this I found this:

> Q1. If data is entered in one or more fields on the main form and the
>   user then clicks the button that opens the message box, is the record
>   saved?
>
> No, if the button is on the main form. However, you sometimes
>   want to save a record (perhaps to print the values) so in the OnClick
>   event you'd have something like If Me.Dirty then Me.Dirty = False in
>   order to force a save.
>
> [Bytes.com - When is a record saved?](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204281-when-record-saved)

So the answer was to add

```
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
```

to the start of the `btnCreateLunchPattern_Click()` procedure.

---

*In light of this - the question doesn't really fit the answer now.  Should I just delete the question?  Reword it so it fits the answer?  Ask on meta?*